# Prove limit of sequence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2n+3}{n^{3}+1} =0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof
Consider

$$\frac{2n+3}{n^{3}+1}< \frac{2}{n^{2}}$$

$$\frac{2}{n^{2}}< \epsilon $$

$$\frac{2}{\epsilon }< n^{2}$$

Choose $\frac{2}{\epsilon }\leq N$ for every $n> N$

then

$$\frac{2}{\epsilon }\leq N^{2}< n^{2}$$

then limit equal 0

Comment: Your first statement does not hold for $n=1$.

Comment: @user389056 thank you

Comment: You could easily use the l'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a proof based on the $\varepsilon$-definition?

> $$\frac{2n+3}{n^{3}+1}< \frac{2}{n^{2}}$$

As pointed out in a comment, this doens't hold.

Make the numerator larger and the denominator smaller. You can say that for all $n \ge 1$:
$$\frac{2n+3}{n^3\color{red}{+1}} \le \frac{2n+3\color{blue}{n}}{n^3} = \frac{5}{n^2}$$

So it suffices to show that for all $\varepsilon >0$, you can find $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $\tfrac{5}{n^2} < \varepsilon$:
$$\frac{5}{n^2} < \varepsilon \iff n > \sqrt{\tfrac{5}{\varepsilon}}$$
You can take any $N \ge \sqrt{\tfrac{5}{\varepsilon}}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can write like:

$$\frac{2n+3}{n^{3}+1}=\frac{n(2+3/n)}{n^{3}(1+1/n^3)}=\frac{2+3/n}{n^{2}(1+1/n^3)}$$

And the statement follows when $n \rightarrow \infty$.